# PotPlayer Crashes when changing Audio Stream

Tags: audio, drivers, video, vlc-media-player, daum-pot-player

I am trying to change the audio stream when watching a video in [Daum PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/). Only, as soon as I change the audio stream from the default to the alternative audio, the entire application becomes unresponsive for several minutes and I have to force close it with task manager.

I looked around and found that [NVIDIA 391.xx drivers can be buggy](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/106050-w10-video-start-freeze.html) with things like this and so I checked my drivers, but I'm running 425.31.

The strangest part is that I was able to change audio streams in VLC without any noticeable issues. I just completely uninstalled and reinstalled PotPlayer and the issue still persists. Is there anything else I can do?

As was suggested in the comments below, I have also made sure that [seamless playback](https://wiki.mikejung.biz/PotPlayer#Potplayer_Playback_Settings) was disabled in the settings, and this has produced no more fruitful results.

Comment: Try to disable [seamless playback](https://wiki.mikejung.biz/PotPlayer#Potplayer_Playback_Settings).

Comment: @harrymc Appreciate the suggestion, but I checked and it's already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the problem is with any hardware driver, since the problem
does not arrive with VLC.

It is much more likely is with either:

1. A bug in PotPlayer
2. A bad video/audio codec

For the second problem, try to install a good codecs pack, such as the
[K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

The first problem is unsolvable, except perhaps by waiting for a future
version of PotPlayer that fixes the problem.
You may accelerate the process by posting a bug report on the
[PotPlayer Forums](https://potplayer.daum.net/forum/).
In the meantime you could use another player, perhaps the excellent VLC,
but there are many more such products
(K-Lite will install one for you).

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me from time to time as well. What I usually do is switch the streams, not using the menu, but by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. 
It fails more times than it succeeds, but with a little patience it usually helps... You just have to try a few times.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, unfortunately I tried this, and it did not give any more fruitful results. As soon as I change the audio stream, the entire application goes totally unresponsive and I have to force close it. I am able to get the exact same files to switch audio streams in VLC so I'm really not sure what the issue is exactly. I might just have to use VLC for these files, but that would be rather disappointing as I think PotPlayer is a much better player. Appreciate the advice nevertheless...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The workaround is to make sure you set the preferred language in Audio/Language or simply use Preferred Steam # in the same options area. This way PotPlayer will start with the audio track you want.